# Display Textbox value in paragraph tag

Tags: laravel, view, html-email, laravel-5.6

I'm sending mail. I'm getting value from textbox, while i send mail i can't get it as paragraph.

For Example:

Textbox value = `Hi
                I'm Laravel`

But in mail inbox = `Hi I'm Laravel`

Getting Value in Blade:

```
<textarea style="width: 100%;" name="message" cols="40" rows="10" required></textarea>
```

In Mail Blade (which display in email inbox):

```
<p>{{ $message }}</p>
```

Comment: What output do you expect? An unstyled p tag looks like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use any **text editors** like https://www.tiny.cloud/ insted of textarea. 
or you need to send the **data with html tags**